# Express basic module use within a view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module

I working on developing an app using express/nodejs. This is what my `routes/index.js` file looks like, as you can see I am trying to include a `sidebar` module and access it within the `index` view:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sidebar = require('./modules/sidebar');

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

this is what my `routes/modules/sidebar.js` looks like:

```
module.exports.showSystemMenu = function(){
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('app-settings-wrapper')[0]; 
    elem.classList.toggle('app-settings-wrapper-exposed');
}
```

In my view (`index`) when I try to access the module function, I am getting an error that `showSystemMenu` is not a function:

```
$scope.showSystemSelect = sidebar.showSystemMenu();
```

I appreciate any clarification as to why I am getting this error and how to resolve.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depending on how the `index` view is being rendered, you may be able to use: `res.render('index', { sidebar: sidebar });`. If the view is rendered server-side, this will provide `sidebar` as a "local" variable by the same name. However, if it's rendered client-side, as the use of `$scope` might suggest, then `sidebar.js` will need to be served to the client -- `<script src="/path/to/sidebar.js"></script>`. Note that `module.exports` doesn't exist client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client side and server side are two different pieces.

Everything that happens in your routes.js or app.js is called the server side. The rendered views are your client side. 
Calling server side code from the client side (like you are doing it) is not possible.

You could use:

a) pass the module to the client side. e.g. `res.render('index', {moment: moment});` This call would pass momentJS from the server side to the client side. (just an example)

or

b) extract the code from your module `routes/modules/sidebar.js` and implement it in your view as a general JS client side function. E.g. implement it in your view in a script tag.

Comment: Ah! thanks for the clarification. So essentially, modules are used to organize/modulate server side logic and determine what happens in the view and index.js is the server side code so I would essentially have to use any modules within this file to figure out what markup should be rendered and pass it in a JSON object in to the view?

Comment: Would this be more appropriate as an angular module?

Comment: In this case, an Angular Module would be probably the best solution. It looks like it has nothing to do with the server side logic.